# delay prevent keypad input till it ednds

Tags: arduino, delay

I am trying to set the delay of a blinking led using 4*4 keypad, but when the delay is large u have to wait for it to end so u can enter another num using the keypad.
so how can I get the input of the keypad while the delay is on ?

```
void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key != NO_KEY) {
    if (key != 'A' && key != 'B' && key != 'C' && key != 'D' && key != '*' && key != '#') {

      Serial.print(key - 48);
      value = value + key;
      num = value.toInt();
    }
  }

  if (key == 'D'){
    wait = num;
    value = "";
  }

  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  delay(wait);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
  delay(wait);
}
```

Comment: see the BlinkWithoutDelay example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`millis()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function to create a blink without delay function and call it after a keypress. Also, there is a good example in [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay).

So you can rewrite your code with something like this:

```
int wait;
int ledState = LOW; // ledState used to set the LED

unsigned long currentMillis, previousMillis;

void blink_without_delay()
{
    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= wait)
    {
        // save the last time you blinked the LED
        previousMillis = currentMillis;

        // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
        if (ledState == LOW)
        {
            ledState = HIGH;
        }
        else
        {
            ledState = LOW;
        }

        // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
        digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    }
}

void setup()
{
    // Do your setup in here
}

void loop()
{
    char key = keypad.getKey();

    if (key != NO_KEY)
    {
        if (key != 'A' && key != 'B' && key != 'C' && key != 'D' && key != '*' && key != '#')
        {

            Serial.print(key - 48);
            value = value + key;
            num = value.toInt();
        }
    }

    if (key == 'D')
    {
        wait = num;
        value = "";
    }

    blink_without_delay();
}
```